# Short story involving a lost-tech green glass highway in Australia

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

My mom's been wondering if I could find this story but I really can't without more specific details than she can give me. It's rather old, she guessed somewhere in the 1960s or 70s. The story wasn't centered about the science fiction aspects from what she remembers, it was more of a murder mystery or detective story that involved a lot of science fiction elements.

There was a highway that was made of a heavy, green glass that was uncovered in the sand in Australia after the technology to create it has been long lost. People use it to get from place to place extremely fast, e.g. going from Perth to Sydney would only take an hour. The author described Australia in great detail, and she recalls that the descriptions were rather awe-inspiring and made her want to visit because of how beautiful it sounded.

More on the highway was that they could repair it but couldn't build more of it due to the loss of technology.  The main character (some sort of detective?) spent a lot of time on this green glass road going places. They also had taken - chipped off - hard chunks and studied them but couldn't reverse-engineer the highway or something like that. The highway worked off of something like magnetism, like having the glass somehow be magnetic.

Comment: A Google search for "green glass highway" yields results from only one author, Julia Buckley. Her mystery novels, _A Dark and Stormy Murder_ (2016), _A Dark and Twisting Path_ (2018), and _Death Waits in the Dark_ (2019), each contain a Green Glass Highway. These novels are much too late to be the object of your search, but maybe Buckley was inspired by the same story. Maybe you can ask her!

Comment: Sounds like something Terry Dowling might write... (but that would be the 80s)

Comment: Kerry Greenwood (of Phryne Fisher fame) write some Australian post-apocalyptic SF in the 90s.

Comment: Although it was published in 2005, Sean Williams's "The Resurrected Man" has some elements in common with this. It stars a private detective in a future Australia. There's a bit where a character mentions it taking "only a few hours to get to Perth or Darwin" - though this might have been by air. Roads are abandoned and in disrepair - though this is due to the discovery of teleportation. The teleport booths have green strips of light on them.

Comment: It's not the answer, but my first thought was Terry Dowling's shatterwrack (but that comes from the vehicles not the road)